# Responsive grid within multiple divs with no stylesheet

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

I am trying to make a layout that looks roughly like this on a computer:
[wide layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obeUz.png)
and this on mobile:
[tall layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be0P3.png)

**I CANNOT use a separate stylesheet or the < style > tag, only the style attributes because it's for a site that doesn't allow these.**

I tried a few different tutorials but can't make it work. Any help is appreciated, cleaner code tips too since I am a beginner. Thank you!

My code:

```html
<div class="window" style="border: hidden; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px red; text-align: center; font-family: monospace; color: black; background-image: linear-gradient(#e6558b,red); padding: 10px; max-width: vw; max-height: 300px; margin: 10px; align-items: center;">
  
  <div class="title" style="background-color: white; border: hidden; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px white; padding: inherit; margin: inherit; align-items: inherit; text-align: inherit; max-height: 75px; font-size: 100%;">
    <p style="font-weight: bold;"><img src=""> title <img src=""></p>
    <p>subtitle</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="miniholder" style="background-color: white; border: hidden; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px white; padding: inherit; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 100px)); grid-gap: 1rem;">
      
    <div class="leftortop" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px; width: 100%; margin: inherit;">
      <p><img src=""></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="rightorbottom" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px; width: 100%; margin: inherit; align-items: inherit;">
      <p style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried initially using flex boxes but I don't know how those really work...
I found [this](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-make-responsive-layouts-without-using-css-media-queries) to be kind of helpful but it wasn't exactly what I wanted for my layout and I also couldn't really get it to work.

Comment: You're not using `<style>` tags (*internal stylesheets*), but the `style=""` attribute (*inline styles*); these two are different. Can you add an actual `<style>` tag?

Comment: @InSync no, the site just ignores anything inside the <style> tag. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You might like to change the title to 'no stylesheet' rather than 'no CSS' jut to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use flexbox with [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).

First, we make `.window` a grid so as to use `gap`; note that [`grid-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap#try_it) is just an alias of `gap`:

```css
.window {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

We then make `.miniholder` a flexbox and allow it to wrap:

```css
.miniholder {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

Now, for the hard part, we arbitrarily choose `2 / 5` as the ratio of `.leftortop` and `.rightorbottom`. Multiple that by another arbitrarily chosen number, we got 150 and 375. These will be `.leftortop` and `.rightorbottom`'s [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)-es, or, basically, `min-width`s. [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) makes them expand their width as much as possible, with `.leftortop` as `2 / 5` as fast as `.rightorbottom`.

```css
.leftortop {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 150px;
}

.rightorbottom {
  flex-grow: 5;
  flex-basis: 375px;
}
```

From these, I think you will be able to figure out the rest.

Try it:

```css
.window, .title, .miniholder, .leftortop, .rightorbottom {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.window {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.miniholder {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.leftortop {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 150px;
}

.rightorbottom {
  flex-grow: 5;
  flex-basis: 375px;
}


/* Demo only */

.window, .title, .miniholder, .leftortop, .rightorbottom {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.leftortop, .rightorbottom {
  outline: 2px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="title">Header</div>
  <div class="miniholder">
    <div class="leftortop">Left content here</div>
    <div class="rightorbottom">Right content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner; use {flex, flex-wrap, gap/justify-content} on the container, {max-width/width with percentage(i.e - if you need 3 elements inside the parent you put 30% and add some gap) } on the child elements.

If you do a lil google you can figure out everything.